# What am I doing wrong with sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, cookies

so Ive finally deployed my app and resolved all the CORS issues, but I have a problem with user authentification. I can log-in, but when I refresh a site I get automaticly logged out -> on all browsers beside Mozilla Firefox, there it works somehow.

**userContext.js** -> Front-end

```
    //XXX Login
const login = () => {
    Axios.post(`${apiUrl}/users/login`, {
        userName: nameLog,
        userPassword: passwordLog,
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response.data.errors) {
            setUser(response.data.name);
            setUserId(response.data.user_id);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            const errors = response.data.errors;
            console.log(errors);
            processErrors(errors);
        }
    });
};

//Checking if user is logged in on every refresh of a page
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`${apiUrl}/users/login`).then((response, err) => {
        console.log("GET /login RESPONSE: ", response);
        if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
            setUser(response.data.user[0].name);
            setUserId(response.data.user[0].user_id);
        }
    });
}, []);
```

First call is a **POST** request, thats when user logs in using form on my site.

And second one is a **GET** request, that checks if the session returns loggedIn true, this is called on every refresh of a page as it is inside useEffect hook.

Then I update my userState which acts as auth if user is allowed to do some action or not.

**userRoutes.js** -> Back-end

```
//Login user
router.post(
    "/login",
    [
        check("userName").exists().notEmpty().withMessage("Username is empty.").isAlpha().isLength({ min: 3, max: 40 }),
        check("userPassword").exists().notEmpty().withMessage("Password is empty.").isLength({ min: 3, max: 60 }).escape(),
    ],
    (req, res) => {
        const valErr = validationResult(req);
        if (!valErr.isEmpty()) {
            console.log(valErr);
            return res.send(valErr);
        }
        const name = req.body.userName;
        const password = req.body.userPassword;
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
        db.query(sql, name, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!result.length > 0) {
                res.send({ errors: [{ msg: "User doesn't exist" }] });
            } else {
                //compare hashed password from front end with hashed password from DB
                bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (error, match) => {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    //if passwords match send -> create session and send user data
                    if (match) {
                        req.session.user = result;
                        res.send({ user_id: result[0].user_id, name: result[0].name });
                    } else {
                        res.send({ errors: [{ msg: "Wrong username or password" }] });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
);

//Checking if user is logged in and if so, sending user's data to front-end in session
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    console.log("GET /login SESSION: ", req.session);
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user });
    } else {
        res.send({ loggedIn: false });
    }
});
```

Again first one is for the **POST** request, where I create session and send it in response filled with user's data (name,id) to front-end (then I update my states accordingly).

Second one belongs to the **GET** request and returns false if user is not logged in or true + user's data. Then once again I update my states.

However this doesnt work and I dont know why. As I mentioned it returns loggedIn: false on every browser besides Mozzilla Firefox.

This is my first time dealing with sessions and cookies so what am I missing here?

By the way the site url is here if that helps: [LINK](https://todo-react-node.netlify.app/), I left some console.logs() to display responses.

**EDIT:** adding all middleware

**app.js** -> main nodejs file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes.js");
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: [
            "http://localhost:3000",
            "https://todo-react-node.netlify.app",
        ],
        methods: ["GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE"],
        credentials: true, //allowing cookies
    })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("SESSION 2 : ", req.session);
    console.log("Cookies 2 : ", req.cookies);
    next();
});

app.use(
    session({
        key: "userID",
        secret: "subscribe",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);

app.use("/users", userRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so finally Ive managed to solve this issue with sessions and cookies. **Solution at the end.**

**What was causing problems?**

**Cross domain cookies (probably)**. As Ive mentioned everything worked fine when Ive hosted my app on localhost, but as soon as Ive deployed my app to 2 different hostings (Netlify - front end, Heroku - back end) my cookies werent coming trough.

Ive actually managed to send cookie by

```
res.cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", {sameSite: "none" secure: true})
```

, however It was standalone cookie and not associated with a session.

Sure why dont you edit your settings in express-session then? Ive tried -> didnt work. My session was never created. I could only send standalone cookie.

And **another problem I couldnt delete this cookie** in browser after being set, nor I could modify it. Ive tried `res.clearCookie("cookie_name")` or setting maxAge attribute to -1, nothing worked.

After googling and watching a lot of videos I found out that sending and receiving cookies from different domains is restricted because of security.

**SOLUTION -> How did I fix the problem?**

Well Ive came upon a [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJwHevf2wYE) on YouTube, that showed how to host full-stack application on Heroku. That way your front end and back end are on the same domain and  voilà sessions and cookies are working properly. Basically it goes like this:

**1)** Build your React app
**2)** In /server (main back end folder) create /public folder and move content of your /client/build directory here
**3)** In your back end main file (app.js in my case) add `app.use(express.static("public"));` to serve your front end.
**4)** Change cors settings to:

```
    app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "your Heroku app url",
        credentials: true, //allowing cookies
    }));
```

**5)** Change express-session settings

```
    app.use(
    session({
        name: "name of session",
        key: "your key",
        secret: "your secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        },
    }));
```

**6)** Fix your routes for API calls (currently what Im working on)

**7)** Host it

**Create session:**

`req.session.SESSION_NAME = session_data;` Note that **SESSION_NAME has to be identical with "name"** attribute's value you have declared in step 5

**Delete session:**

`res.clearCookie("SESSION_NAME"); req.session.destroy();`

Hope this helps somebody, who encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` only called once if you are using `[]` in useEffect function.

Try to take it out(or add the suitable dependencies) and add a `console.log()` in that function to test out.

Furthermore, read the following [article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to gain some insight about `useEffect`.

Comment: Ive removed it but it didnt solve the problem. I still get logged out when I refresh the page manually.